# Visual Studio (2019) and adding/removing files in relation to local Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When using another IDE, adding/renaming/moving/deleting a file would also be propagated to the underlying version control system.

Now we use **Visual Studio (2019)** in combination with **GIT**.
When I now add a file using the **VS** `File -> New -> File...` option, this file is not automatically added (I don't mean committed of course) to the **GIT** local repository.
The same thing goes for moving/renaming and deleting files.

I could not find any setting inside **VS** and when I look at the **GIT** extension inside the Marketplace there're so many, I can't seem to find the one I need.

Comment: Why would it be automatically added?

Comment: @Acorn Normally when you add a file, you want to add it to your GIT repo too. You can start typing stuff like `git add` but why not let the IDE do it for you after the file has been added/created? Same goes for renaming/deleting files...

Comment: In many cases, yes. But it may be a mistake, or I may decide later to discard the changes, or I may want to put the file in another commit, or I may be working on something else on my staging area at the time... There are many reasons why it is a bad idea to add it automatically and it would be completely unexpected for most users. Any and all actions on a repository state should be explicit.

Comment: @Acorn I know there are plenty of cases where this is not wanted, but plenty where it is - I think this depends on the way you personally work with your IDE and version control. So I think in your opinion it's a bad idea, because of the way you work. In my case, I'm certain it will greatly benefit my work. But OK - make it something optional, I don't care - It's something I've been doing or years and never had any problems with... and I'm sure there are plenty of users that would love it too.

Comment: @Acron just to make things really clear: I DON'T want to automatically COMMIT changes - I just change the way the file is tracked by the local copy, this way I can also easily stash my changes when I need to switch branches.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you just want to stash them. My answer above was talking about stashing. Committing would be even worse, of course! Perhaps someone knows how to automate this in VS, I don't know, I have not used VS for half a decade or more, sorry.